# Как в phpshtorm настроить генерацию кода

Tags: phpstorm, symfony2, phpunit

В общем есть класс например контроллера, на symfony, нужно сделать так чтобы при создании класса теста генерировались все методы класса и дата провайдеры на них.

Сейчас генерируется только namespace и имя класса.

Answer (score 1):

Не думаю, что вообще возможно сгенерировать всё в точности так, как вы указали. Но максимально приблизиться к результату можно через редактирование шаблонов файлов.

Подробнее здесь: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/creating-and-editing-file-templates.html